# "Or" statement - ORMLite

Tags: ormlite

I'm tring to do this query with ORMLite but I just can't use the or() statement properly.

> SELECT DISTINCT x FROM x x INNER JOIN x.w w WHERE :date >= x.startDate
>   AND w.company.id = :companyId AND w.status = :status AND x.status =
>   :status AND (x.endDate = NULL OR x.endDate >= :date)

My code:

```
QueryBuilder<x, Integer> xQB = this.xDao.queryBuilder();
xQB.where().eq("status", StatusEnum.ENABLED).and().le("startDate", date)
.and().ge("endDate", date).or().isNull("endDate");
```

If date is less than startDate this state stil returning values of endDate equal null. If I remove the or() statement everything works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a feeling you are getting confused around the `AND` and `OR` grouping.  Any `and()` or `or()` operation (without args) takes the previous element on the stack and combines it with the next argument and then pushes the result on the stack.  So `a AND b AND c OR e` turns into approximately `(((a AND b) AND c) OR e)`.

The `Where` class also has `and(...)` and `or(...)` method that take arguments which wrap the comparison in parenthesis.  This is useful in situations like yours when you need to be explicit about what tow things you are comparing.  I'd change your's to be:

```
QueryBuilder<x, Integer> xQB = this.xDao.queryBuilder();
Where<x, Integer> where = xQB.where();
where.and(where.eq("status", StatusEnum.ENABLED),
    where.and(where.le("startDate", date),
        where.or(where.ge("endDate", date), where.isNull("endDate"))));
```

This should generate approximately `(a AND (b AND (c OR d)))' which seems to be what you want.

To see the various ways to construct queries, check out the docs:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/building-queries

Comment: Now it's working fine!

Thank you for your better explanation, I wasn't understanding based only on ORMLite docs.